# Stackoverflow calling toString() on classes with list elements that reference each other

Tags: java

I have a User class with a list of Teams:

```
class User {
  List<Team> teams...

  public String toString() {
    return "a user and " + teams.toString();
  }
}
```

and a Team class with a list of Users:

```
class Team {
  List<User> users...

  public String toString() {
    return "a team and " + users.toString();
  }
}
```

I create a user and team like this:

```
User aUser = new User();
List<User> usersList = new ArrayList<User>();
usersList.add(aUser);

Team aTeam = new Team();
List<Team> teamsList = new ArrayList<User>();
teamsList.add(aTeam);

aUser.setTeams(teamsList);
aTeam.setUsers(userList);
```

But when I call user.toString() I'm getting a StackOverflowError because of the cycle between User and Team.

Any ideas of how to get around this cycle?

Comment: Yes, that would happen. What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was instead of calling toString() to get a textual representation of the cyclic objects, just call getX() on the object(s) to get the relevant data:

```
class User {
  List<Team> teams...

  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = ...
    sb.append("a user and ");

    for (Team team : teams) {
      sb.append("[a team with id ")
      sb.append(team.getId());
      sb.append("and team name ");
      sb.append(team.getName());
      sb.append("] ");
    } 
    return sb.toString();
  }
}
```

(and vice vera for the toString() implementation on the Team class)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because calling a `List`'s `toString()` method will in turn call it's element's `toString()` method to append one by one of the element's `toString()` returned value to one string and returns.

For your context, `users.toString()` will result in `user` instance's `toString()` call of `User` class: which in turn call the `teams.toString()` method, resulting in team instance's `toString()` of  `Team` class. Hence, a cycle is happening, calling the function over function.

However, as the official [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) suggests:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the
>   toString method returns a string that *"textually represents"* this
>   object. The result should be a concise but informative representation
>   that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all
>   subclasses override this method.

So you should not return same representation for objects of different Class: which is probably you were trying to do.

Comment: If you *really* wanted the many-to-many relationship, *and* wanted the `toString` method to render out correctly on both, you could create a custom class extending from ArrayList, and override its `toString` to call a different method that `Team` and `User` both implement, e.g. a `getName` call — seems like more hassle than it's worth to be honest though! :)

Comment: yes, i am not sure why the OP is even bothering to return one Class's `toString()` from another Class's `toString()`.

Comment: I presume he's looking to "overload" the `toString` to show both sides of his many-to-many relationship, say "Dave Grohl is a member of Nirvana, Queens of the Stone Age and the Foo Fighters" is you call `User.toString()` and also "The Foo Fighters are made up of Dave Grohl, Nate Mendel, Pat Smear, Taylor Hawkins and Chris Shiflett", if you call `Team.toString()` (but without the recursion :) )

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental problem here is poor design. You're correct that there's a cycle. To solve it, don't include any references to `Team` in `User`; instead, just list which `User` belong to a `Team` inside each `Team`'s list. To figure out later on which people belong to which teams, you can iterate through a list of `Team`s, or use some other data structure.

In general, you always want to keep the more atomic elements (in this case `User`, since `User`s are the atoms which make up `Team`s) independent of references to the composite elements.